# Permissions for Modifying User Attributes?

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory

I'm working on a PowerShell script for a colleague that changes/clears a specific user attribute for all the users in a forest using Set-ADUser. The script is done and is working properly but I want to add code to properly check if the user running the script has the necessary permissions to modify user attributes. Currently I have Set-ADUser in a try/catch block. A specific access rights exception in the catch block causes the script to terminate. This, in my mind, is a really janky way of doing this. I'd rather have a proper permissions check based on ACLs/ACEs that lives in the readiness check section.

I haven't spent much time in AD and thought I'd reach out to folks who are more knowledgeable in this area. So my question is what would be the best or 'best practice' way to check that the user account running the script has permission to set/clear user attributes?

Comment: You’d have to check this permission for each target prior to setting as the objects could have different permissions. I’d probably stick with the try catch and spend effort on figuring out what specific issue is causing the script to terminate instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Script termination on encountering the access rights exception is by design.

Comment: Then it seems you're doing it pretty well.